# The way simulation in Verilog/vwf define assignment

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, quartus

So I just started learning Verilog using Quartus II, and I have been creating simple codes to run synthesis and simulation to get used to the software. This code is actually from the document I am reading.

I actually solved the problem but didn't understand why. If you see the code all the way down, wire i0, i5, i2, i3 are defined. i5 USED to be i1.

When I ran the simulation with i1, it would give this error.

```
 # Top level modules:
 # work
 # Model Technology ModelSim ALTERA vlog 10.1d Compiler 2012.11 Nov  2 2012
 # -- Compiling module work_vlg_sample_tst
 # -- Compiling module work_vlg_check_tst
 # -- Compiling module work_vlg_vec_tst
 # ** Error: Practice1.vt(182): 'i1' already declared in this scope.
 # ** Error: c:/altera/13.0sp1/modelsim_ase/win32aloem/vlog failed.
 # Executing ONERROR command at macro ./Practice1.do line 4
```

So I took a look at the Practice1.vt, it would give following.

```
*// assign statements (if any)                          
work i1 (
// port map - connection between master ports and signals/registers   
   .i0(i0),
   .i2(i2),
   .i3(i3),
   .i5(i5),
   .s(s),
   .y(y)
);
//*
```

**Why is simulation using i1 to define that part of the statement? What does this part of the code do?**

```
module work(
input wire[1:0] s,
input wire i0, i5, i2, i3,
output reg y
);
always @(s)
begin
    if (s==2'b00)
        y = i0;
    else if (s==2'b01)
        y = i5;
    else if (s==2'b10)
        y = i2;
    else if (s==2'b11)
        y = i3;
    else
        y = y;
end
endmodule
```

Sorry for the weird question...Just a beginner here.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Not related to your issue directly, but `@(s)` should be `@*` (if it needs to be pre-2001 compliant then it should be `@(s or i0 or i5 or i2 or i3)`). Quartus and other synthesizers may not care about combinational sensitivity lists; Verilog simulators do care.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming line 182 was

```
work i1(
```

or it could have been

```
.i1(i1)
```

It would help to have pointed out the original line of code that the error message mentioned.

The `i1` in `work i1` is an instance name. Verilog allows hierarchical references to names from one module to another. See section **23.6 Hierarchical names** in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM. You could have fix your problem by chain `work i1` to `work w` instead of changing the wire and port names.

Also note that the names of the ports in `work` don't have to match the signal names in the module that instantiates. You did have to change the port i1 in work. You could have also done:

```
work i1 (
// port map - connection between master ports and signals/registers   
   .i0(i0),
   .i2(i2),
   .i3(i3),
   .i1(i5),
   .s(s),
   .y(y)
);
```

But generally it's not good coding practice to have signal names and instance names looking so similar.

Comment: The code we are currently talking about is from VT file. The vt file is generated (I think) when I run the compilation. Currently, I do not know how to change that chain. That's why I took an easy way around and changed variables.

If you can tell me how to change that chain, that would be great.
Thanks a lot for the help